# `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" } con laravel socialite

Tags: laravel, http, google-api, laravel-10, socialite

Hola estoy creando una aplicacion web que necesita crear un usuario a partir de tus datos en google, el flujo es asi, el usuario se redirecciona con `return Socialite::driver('google')->scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile','openid'])->redirect();` y ya que fue redireccionado y selecciona su perfil google lo redirecciona al callback donde obtengo su token y lo redirecciono a un formulario donde el usuario debe de llenar ciertos campos necesarios para su usuario en mi sistema y ya que ingrese sus datos, estos datos los almaceno junto a sus datos de google, pero a la hora de darle submit al formulario me salta este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya intente ponerle scopes a mi driver pero aun asi me da error, intente pedir mas permisos en mi cloud pero aun asi no funciona, este es mi codigo:

```
 public function store(UserRequest $request)
{
    $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->userFromToken($request->google_token);
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $googleUser->getName(),
        'email' => $googleUser->getEmail(),
        'nickname' => $request->nickname,
        'password' => $request->password
    ]);
    $user->degree()->associate($request->degree);
    return redirect()->route('auth.index')->with('info', 'se ha creado el usuario correctamente');
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 */
public function create()
{
    $token = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user()->token;
    return view('auth.sigin', ['token' => $token->token, 'degrees' => Degree::all()]);
}
```

las rutas:

```
Route::get('/terminos-y-condiciones', function () {
})->name('agreement');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function () {
Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
Route::middleware([])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'index'])->name('login.show');
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    Route::get('/recuperar-contraseña', [PasswordRecoveryController::class, 
'showRecoveryForm'])->name('password.recovery');
    Route::post('/recuperar-contraseña', [PasswordRecoveryController::class, 'submit'])- 
 >name('password.recovery.send');
    Route::get('/recuperar-contraseña/enviado', [PasswordRecoveryController::class, 
'showSendedView'])->name('password.recovery.sended');
    Route::get('/redirect', [AuthController::class, 'redirect'])->name('google.auth');
    Route::get('/callback', [UserController::class, 'create'])- 
 >name('google.callback.create');
    Route::post('/callback', [UserController::class, 'store'])- 
 >name('google.callback.store');
    });
 });
```

las rutas de redirect de googl
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y los permisos que solicito
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es simplemente las urls de redireccionamiento que tienes definidas, revisa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que obtienes:

> Client error: "POST [https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token%22)
> resulted in a "400 Bad request" response: { "error":
> "invalid_grant","error_description": "Bad Request" }

Es debido a un problema de autorización de Google. Al revisar tu configuración de "URI de redireccionamiento autorizado" veo que usas urls de "localhost", incluso son urls no cifradas, esto en realidad es lo que causa el problema por cuestiones de seguridad.

Usa urls con certificado de seguridad y que estas puedan accederse al menos en tu LAN.

En todas mis "ID de cliente para Aplicación web"  no tengo definido como "Orígenes autorizados de JavaScript" para usar con solicitudes urls de localhost ni urls sin certificado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al solucionar lo anterior, si tienes un problema de permisos, en el mensaje se indicará si el "scope" de permisos es el adecuado.

Comment: y como puedo hacer para que sea en mi entorno de pruebas??

Comment: @LuisGarcia, primeramente, tienes una forma de refrescar el Token? no la veo en tu código.